# How to ensure my SVN repository is not corrupt

Tags: svn

I am working in a small shop and I am currently the only one in development (and that means everything, from setting up SVN and JBoss server to doing the actual programming), apart from other things.

That causes that I am the only one using the SVN repository, and usually just writting (sometimes I need to do a diff or revert some changes to the last version).

I have included backups of the SVN repository in our main backups, but I am afraid of the possibility of the SVN becoming corrupt and not realizing it until I try to check out a project (even with a backup, restoring your work from a tape several months old would mean a lot of work lost).

Can I assume that, as long as I have no problems committing to the SVN, the repository is ok? Otherwise, there is some operation (better if it can be automated) that I can do to check it regularly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> svnadmin verify REPOS_PATH

This command verifies the data stored in the repository. It should be executed on the server which stores SVN repository.

Comment: looks like it... now I have to find a way to automate it.